# Как создать инсталлятор конфигурации laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу при помощи контроллера указать данные для подключения к БД, чтобы выполнились миграции, заполнились другие настройки сайта. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что при использовании `config` функции используются старые данные, пробовал менять env напрямую, но тогда появляется проблема с перезагрузкой сервера, чтобы конфигурация применилась. Уже не знаю, что делать, помогите! Кэш пробовал чистить при помощи `Artisan::call('optimize:clear')`. Это не помогает, словно он до сих пор используется.

Comment: Не надо перегружать сервер после изменения .env, нужно запустить [php artisan config:clear](https://coderoad.ru/37849436/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-env-%D0%B2-Laravel-5-2) что очистит закешированные настройки. Только учтите что в одном и том же запросе или консольном запуске (Web vs CLI) это сделать не получится, так как при запуске PHP конфига уже был сформирован и находится в памяти для исполнения.

Comment: Сервер php сам производит перезапуск после того, как .env изменяется. Только если применить опцию no-reload, тогда всё работает как надо. Это рабочий вариант, но опять же, желательно обойтись без перезапуска консольного сервера. Говорить пользователям, что нужно запускать с опцией no-reload не очень-то хочется.

Comment: Если сервер консольный, тогда остается только запись напрямую в конфигурационные PHP файлы, хотя есть сомнения. Рекомендую настроить php-fpm сервер в связке NGINX/PHP-FPM.

Comment: Возникает ощущение, что конфиг загружается до моего запроса, и, если даже изменить с помощью функции config всё необходимое (в классе репозитория обновляется), то при миграции берутся по прежнему старые данные конфига. Довольно странно, данные в репозитории новые, а при миграции берутся старые. И кэш в этот момент очищаю

Comment: Всё правильно, я поэтому и написал про переход с консольного сервера на PHP-FPM. В консольном PHP код загружается сразу и кэшируется, и его можно применить только после перезапуска. Насчет миграций не знаю в чем может быть дело, но подозреваю что в том же самом.